# Want an explanation for an integral around a circle?

Tags: calculus

I read an integral around circle by using the infinitesimal formula $dS=[dx^2+dy^2]^{1/2}$.
The circumference C was given by:

$\displaystyle \begin{split}
C=&\oint dS=\oint [dx^2+dy^2]^{1/2}&(1)\\
=&2\int^{+R}_{-R}dx[1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2]^{1/2}_{x^2+y^2=R^2} &(2)\\
=&2\int^{+R}_{-R}dx\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{R^2-x^2}}&(3)\\
\end{split}$

However, I'm not sure how did the step $(2)$ to $(3)$ happened, how did $1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2=\frac{R^2}{R^2-x^2}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treating $x,y$ as coordinate functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$, in other words $x,y: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and are both linear, then we get the following,
\begin{align*}x^2 + y^2 = R^2 \Rightarrow xdx+ydy = 0 &\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} \\&= \frac{-x}{y}\Rightarrow 1+ \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 \\&= 1+\frac{x^2}{y^2}\\& = \frac{R^2}{y^2} \\&= \frac{R^2}{R^2-x^2} \end{align*}